# How to configure web.config for WCF Rest Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-config, wcf-binding

I'm creating a WCF Rest website but can't quite figure out how to configure the web.config. I'm seeing some examples online, but they are all non-Rest. I don't know if it makes any difference when it comes to the configuration besides the binding, since it is my first time working with WCF Rest.

I deployed the WCF site to my IIS server and I can access that default WCF page when I go to svc.myproj.com/AccountService.svc. I can even use svcutil to generate the client using the same url, but whenever I try to connect to that service in my client app I get endpoint not found exception.

Any ideas?

Here's my AccountService.svc:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class AccountService {

        [OperationContract]
        public bool IsRegisteredUser(string emailOrUsername)
        {
            return this.GetUser(emailOrUsername) != null;
        }
}
```

And here's my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProj.Services.AccountService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="/AccountService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="MyProj.Services.AccountServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyProj.Services.AccountService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyProj.Services.AccountServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `<enableWebScript />` could you try using `<webHttp/>` to see if that helps inside the behaviour tag and also try changing the decorators of IsRegisteredUser

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/IsRegisteredUser", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool IsRegisteredUser(string emailOrUsername)
{
  return this.GetUser(emailOrUsername) != null;
}
```